# Updating value in MongoDB for value plus 1

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to update a collection on MongoDB (terminal) and replace one of the elements of the collection by adding 1.5 to its value. Take this for example:

```
   db.sensores.insert(
   {
      "timestamp":"2020-05-25T10:30:00Z",
      "sensor_id":1,
      "location_id":1,
      "Ubicacion":"Valladolid",
      "Coordenadas":"41.638597, 4.740186",
      "Medidas":[
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Temperatura",
            "valor":22.08,
            "unidad":"ºC"
         },
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa",
            "valor":34.92,
            "unidad":"%"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2020-05-28T11:30:00Z",
      "sensor_id":1,
      "location_id":2,
      "Ubicacion":"Sevilla",
      "Coordenadas":"37.409311, -5.949939",
      "Medidas":[
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Temperatura",
            "valor":21.12,
            "unidad":"ºC"
         },
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Humedad_relativa",
            "valor":37.7,
            "unidad":"%"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2020-05-28T1:30:00Z",
      "sensor_id":2,
      "location_id":2,
      "Ubicacion":"Sevilla",
      "Coordenadas":"37.409311, -5.949939",
      "medidas":[
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2",
            "valor":2.102,
            "unidad":"gCO2/m2"
         },
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico",
            "valor":0.00272,
            "unidad":"kWh/m2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "timestamp":"2020-05-25T10:30:00Z",
      "sensor_id":2,
      "location_id":1,
      "Ubicacion":"Valladolid",
      "Coordenadas":"41.638597, 4.740186",
      "medidas":[
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Emision_CO2",
            "valor":1.626,
            "unidad":"gCO2/m2"
         },
         {
            "tipo_medida":"Consumo_electrico",
            "valor":0.00146,
            "unidad":"kWh/m2"
         }
      ]
   }
)
```

Under "sensor_id":1 and "location_id":2 there is a value that stands for the temperature (medidas>tipo_medida>temperatura>value). I need to add 1.5 to all those values and this is what I've tried:

--Option1:

```
    db.datos_sensores.update(
   {sensor_id: 2 }, 
   {location_id: 1 },
   { $set:
      {
        "medidas": "tipo_medida",
        details: { "temperatura": value, make: value+1 },
      }
   }
)
```

--Option2:

```
 db.datos_sensores.update({"sensor_id":2, "location_id":1}},
  {$push:{"medidas":{
    $each:[
      {"tipo_medida":"temperatura","valor":+1}]
  }
 }})
```

I've gotten the same error with both of them: uncaught exception: ReferenceError: value is not defined: @(shell):7:20.

Could someone please help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Here is an example from MongoDB Manual: [Update All Documents in an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

Comment: I would have to include every ObjectID manually in the array, right? In that case this wouldn't help cause I have tens of thousands of objects.

Comment: _"I would have to include every ObjectID manually in the array, right?"_ I don't know why you have to include the `ObjectId` in the array - your post question doesn't say anything about ObjectId in the array.

Comment: But the example if the link you sent me is done through ids: 
'''
{ "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 82, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 90, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }

Comment: You look for the example with the title - Update All Documents in an Array. This is relevant to your case.

Comment: I see that you want to update only temperature sub-documents in the array. So see this has the correct examples: [Update All Documents That Match arrayFilters in an Array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-all-documents-that-match-arrayfilters-in-an-array).

Comment: Thanks! Some of these examples are good, my issue is that I should update it only for those in valladolid, so condition has to be location_id=1, and it needs to deduct 1.5 to all those values, so it should include the condition to only affect those in that city plus the operation to substract the desired value from that sub-collection. I'm using smthg like this but I'm not sure how to include the condition plus the operation in there:

Comment: db.datos_sensores.update(
   { },
   { $set: { "medidas.$[elem].mean" : 100 } },
   {
     multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "elem.Temperatura": { $gte: 85 } } ]
   }
)